# Как добавлять в список generic объектов экземпляр generic дочернего типа?

Tags: c#, generics

Есть родительский обобщённый класс ParentGeneric, на который наложено ограничение ParentConstraint.
Почему в список нельзя добавить класс с обобщением ChildConstraint, которое наследуется от ParentConstraint? Ведь ограничение должно позволять создавать обобщения с производными классами.

```
    var list = new List<ParentGeneric<ParentConstraint>>();
    list.Add(new ChildGeneric<ChildConstraint>()); // ошибка конвертации типов
    
    public class ParentGeneric<T> where T : ParentConstraint {}
    
    public class ChildGeneric<T> : ParentGeneric<T> where T : ParentConstraint {}
    
    public class ParentConstraint {}
    
    public class ChildConstraint : ParentConstraint {}
```

Comment: Тут проблема не в ParentGeneric и ChildGeneric, а в ParentConstraint и ChildConstraint. Конкретные типы инвариантны, то что вы пытаетесь сделать - можно сделать только с ковариантными (out) интерфейсами.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал о таких механизмах работы языка. У Вас есть возможность привести пример такой реализации на моей задаче? @PavelMayorov

Comment: лень, если честно, потому и пишу комментарий. Попробуйте сделать интерфейс `IParentGeneric<out T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Тут проблема не в ParentGeneric и ChildGeneric, а в ParentConstraint и ChildConstraint. Конкретные типы инвариантны, то что вы пытаетесь сделать - можно сделать только с ковариантными (out) интерфейсами.

```
public interface IParentGeneric<out T> { }

public class ParentGeneric<T> : IParentGeneric<T> where T : ParentConstraint { }
```

```
var list = new List<IParentGeneric<ParentConstraint>>();
list.Add(new ChildGeneric<ChildConstraint>());
```